Determine if $X^{4}+X^{2}Y^{2} + Y^{3} + Y^{2} -1 \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ is irreducible
I think given polynomial is irreducible. I am trying to prove this using Eisenstein's criterium. Rearranging gives us:
$$
X^{4} + (Y^{2})X^{2} + (Y^{3} + (Y-1)(Y+1))
$$
However I cannot seem to find a polynomial that divides both $Y^{2}$ and $ (Y^{3} + (Y-1)(Y+1))$.

Is $x^2$ after $X^4$ mean to be $X^2$? For the question, see here, for example, or use Eisenstein as they do here.

Hint: rearranging as $Y^3 +(X^2+1)Y^2+X^4-1$ then use Eisenstein criterion.

@Tri, thanks this solved it for me. I didn't think to rearrange in terms of $Y$.
